# SMTP Send Failed Exception: 421: Error: too many messages in one session

Tags: java

Our Application will send an Automation mail while sending failed with Error code **"SMTP Send Failed Exception: 421: Error: too many messages in one session"**

This Problem gets resolved automatically after few minutes.  Hourly 40-50 Mails sent to different Users. But on Everyday this problem arises and failed to send mail and got resolved automatically after few minutes.

This problem is not particular to a specific user.

Below are the logs
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 421 Error: too many messages in one session

```
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2057) ~[mail-1.4.4.jar!/:1.4.4]
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1580) ~[mail-1.4.4.jar!/:1.4.4]
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1097) ~[mail-1.4.4.jar!/:1.4.4]
at com.abc.tools.mail.EMailer$MailTask.call(EMailer.java:213) [classes:na]
at com.abc.tools.mail.EMailer$MailTask.call(EMailer.java:128) [classes:na]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_60]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_60]
```

Could you please let me know what could be the reason.

Comment: Are you sending emails multi-threaded? Have you try reduce the batch size?

Comment: Yes sending the emails in multithreaded but not batch.  Through Application the mail will be triggered and on average 40-50 mail per hour..

Comment: Maybe post the sending email code? 40-50 email per hour doesn't sound like much.

Comment: I got the Answer: Error Code : 421 - Temporary Connection Failure as the messages size exceeds the Default limit (20) of an session.

Refer the Links below,

 http://docs.mailpoet.com/article/49-lists-of-hosts-and-their-sending-limits

 http://msexchangeguru.com/2011/08/18/errors/    
  
  https://www.emailarchitect.net/emailserver/doc/html/smtpd.htm
  https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/657bb5ee-e48b-4a6d-9e2f-ac49b959a1bc.mspx?mfr=true

Now I need to know how the message count is calculated? Please suggest if anyone idea about it?

Comment: Nice - Post your answer to complete your question.

Comment: Could anyone please assist me what makes the Message size exceeds the Default limit...

Comment: Based on that article, message count limit is 20 by default and message size is 2MB. To answer your question, message size could be contributed by attachments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error Code 421: Too Many messages in a session. 
Root Cause: Few limitation was available at IIS, One of the limitation is

Limit Message size